# The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't get rid of this problem in my code, it says `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type`

This is an Angular frontend

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: function (tooltipItem) {
      var label:any = 'Score : ' + Math.round(tooltipItem.yLabel * 100) / 100;
      label += ' | Magnitude : ' + sentimentChartMag[tooltipItem.index] || '';
      return label;
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Why are you typing label as `any`? It's a string.

Comment: For me, I got this error when sorting dates. I had to add valueOf kind of like `Date().valueOf()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I copy the code I have no such error, are you sure it is this part of the code? Also please try to avoid native java functions in typescript, use arrow functions instead. Which data type is sentimentChartMag? Where does it come from, since it has no this Which data type is yLabel? Could it be, that it is a string?

After all it likely should look like this

```
 label: tooltipItem => {
          let label: string  = 'Score : ' + Math.round(Number(tooltipItem.yLabel) * 100) / 100;
          label += ' | Magnitude : ' + this.sentimentChartMag[tooltipItem.index] || '';
          return label;
        }
```